# log4j 2 not creating or logging to file

Tags: java, log4j2

can someone tell me what I am doing silly here ? I cant get this hi to a file.

```
import org.apache.logging.log4j.*;
public class TestLog4J {
    public static final Logger LOGFILE = LogManager.getLogger();
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LOGFILE.debug("hi");
    }
}
```

log4j2.preperties file

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, LOGFILE, stdout
log4j.appender.LOGFILE=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.LOGFILE.File=C:\log.out
log4j.appender.LOGFILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.LOGFILE.layout.conversionPattern=%m%n

log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

I am running like below,

```
java -cp C:\javalibs\apache-log4j-2.17.2-bin\log4j-api-2.17.2.jar;C:\javalibs\apache-log4j-2.17.2-bin\log4j-core-2.17.2.jar;. TestLog4J
```

But I don't see the file created at location on written to. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Update : I saw the line in debug "java -cp C:\javalibs\apache-log4j-2.17.2-bin\log4j-api-2.17.2.jar;C:\javalibs\apache-log4j-2.17.2-bin\log4j-core-2.17.2.jar;. TestLog4J", and changed the logging level in application from debug to error, now i can see stdout appender is working, but file write still isn't, and also i don't get why the default logger was not taken even though available.

Comment: Your `log42.properties` file is not in the proper format: you are using the configuration format from Log4j 1.x. Either convert the configuration file to a Log4j2 format (XML is much simpler than the properties format) or use the [Log4j 1.x bridge](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/migration.html).

Comment: Your classpath does not contain the log4j configuration properties file, but it must in order for it to be scanned. Check the [doc](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html)

Comment: In both cases (wrong log4j filename or file not on classpath), would Log4j2 not emit a warning that no log is written because it is not configured? Log4j1 actually did...

Comment: @HiranChaudhuri: there are nice warning messages at the `WARN` level, but since the status logger loggs only `ERROR`s by default, they are not printed. You should probably report it.

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz thanks, that was the reason. now  I am able to write to file, and also I changed to XML

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz This does not make sense. I was referring to warnings if log4j is not configured. In that case it cannot be configured to just emit ERRORs. Or are you saying that the behaviour has changed for log4j2?

Comment: @HiranChaudhuri: No, it does not make sense and it is clearly a minor bug. I have opened [LOG4J2-3486](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-3486) for this issue.